# Django 1.5: How to show a preselected value passed from a view into a template select

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

This is my problem:

I'm building a HTML page that shows user data.

In the registration user data page I collect data in this way:

```
<div class="large-3 columns">
     <label for="pizza">Type of Pizza;
          <select id="pizza" name="pizza" >
                 {% for key, value in pizza.items %}
                      <option value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
                 {% endfor %}
          </select>
     </label>
</div>
```

In this way the user can select his favorite type of pizza.

Then, users can change his favorite pizza in a ChangeUserData page.

I want to show in the select field, a data passed from my view (his favorite pizza), with the possibility of change that data with others (a new type of pizza), if the user want to do that.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [forms framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/). I'll assume the pizza is stored in the UserProfile model.

First, create a forms.py file in your app that defines the form:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['favorite_pizza', ]
```

Then, you could use an UpdateView or some custom view to use the form. Let's assume we have an update view:

```
class UserProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'your_template'
    model = UserProfile
    form_class = UserProfileForm
```

Now, on to the template 'your_template':

```
<form method='post' action='.'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='Confirm pizza change'/>
</form>
```

This way, django will render the select based on the choices you should specify in the definition of the favorite_pizza field. Also, this will handle setting the value to what the user has previously chosen.

Edit: I recommend doing the same in the registration page. In general, it will be a lot faster and safer to use the forms framework whenever you can to handle user input